# Flutter Error running Gradle:

Tags: flutter

E:\Users\JOSHUA ELI\OneDrive\Proyectos\Código\Flutter\new_set>flutter run

Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling
software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".

Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

Initializing gradle...                                              1.1s

Resolving dependencies...

- Error running Gradle:
  ProcessException: Process "E:\Users\JOSHUA ELI\OneDrive\Proyectos\Código\Flutter\new_set\android\gradlew.bat" exited
  abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'E:\Users\JOSHUA ELI\OneDrive\Proyectos\Código\Flutter\new_set\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
  >   Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please
  >   move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details. This warning can be disabled
  >   by adding the line 'android.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the project directory.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with
  --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
  Command: E:\Users\JOSHUA ELI\OneDrive\Proyectos\Código\Flutter\new_set\android\gradlew.bat app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

---

En teoría ya vi varios posts en inglés y no sé qué onda con este error, algunos sugieren que me vaya al repositorio de Flutter, ósea

flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle

Y lo que entendí, algunos sugieren que cambie

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}
```

por

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }
}
```

Y ya hice el cambio pero no logré ningún cambio, intenté crear una nueva carpte de Flutter create ¿alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resultó ser mucho más simple de lo que imaginé, básicamente sólo resultó en ser un error con los caracteres ASCII, creo que leí mal el mensaje, si alguien tiene este error en específico sólo tiene que cambiar la ruta, cambiando cualquier carpeta como por ejemplo yo que en una carpeta tenía

'Código'

Y creo que debido a errores del Framework no acepte caracteres como el 'ó', de ese modo cambiar a

'Codigo'

Answer (score 1):

A mi también me sucedió y es porque en la carpetea donde tenia el proyecto tenia un carácter que no lo entendía al momento de compilar ese carácter puede ser desde una tilde hasta cualquier otro signo o la letra 'Ñ' lo mejor es cambiar de nombre o borrar ese carácter.

Answer (score 1):

Pues a mi ese error me sale así, no se que hacerle, tienen alguna idea

```sh
flutter build apk  --release
```

Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\WorkSpace\Flutter\flutter_ui_planets\android\app\build.gradle' line: 31
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Malformed \uxxxx encoding.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                       9.6s

Comment: La sección de respuestas es para las propuestas de solución, no para más preguntas. Si tienes una nueva pregunta por hacer, [formúlala](/questions/ask), leyendo [ask].